# Get a field's required attribute in frontend form

Tags: templating, field, frontend, frontend-form

I am trying to get the required attribute of a field in a frontend form. I know this attribute only makes sense in the context of an entry type. Doing this

`craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('handle')`

returns a FieldModel object which has no context to any entry type. This way I can get the field name and the instructions for example. In Craft we set the required attribute in the entry type editor. So my question is:

*How can I get a field's required attribute in the context of a specific entry type?*

Edit: My goal is to create a frontend form of an entry type and have every change to the field's required flags in the backend automatically reflected in the frontend form: `<input required ...>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way to get a specific field for a model but you can get all and loop through them

```
<!-- fetch all fields for your entryType -->
{% for field in craft.entries.section('yourSection').type('yourEntryType').first.getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
    <!-- loop them and check the handle if it is your field -->
    {% if field.getField().handle == "yourFieldHandle" %}
        <!-- the required attribute -->
        {% set required = field.required %}
        {{ field.getField().name }}
        {{ field.getField().instructions }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: if you really want to have only one field instead of the array I could create php code for you but since many people refuse to use php in craft I presented the "slower" twig method

Edit: There is a `required` property in both the `FieldLayoutFieldModel` (stored above in `field`) and in the `FieldModel` (`field.getField()` above). What we want as the required flag of the entry type is the first: `field.required`. This is what appears to be the little red asterisk in Craft's backend.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply. No I want all fields - was just written generally. What I noticed: Calling `getFields()` on a FieldLayout returns an array of `FieldLayoutFieldModel`s with the desired property `required` for this entry type but without properties like `name` or `instructions`. These two can only(?) be found in the appropriate `FieldModel` which I can get with `...getFieldLayout().getFields()[0].field`. Wow this gets almost too clunky for a Twig template.

Comment: I updated my answer in order to display the name and the instructions. You just have to use the `getField()` function

Comment: I updated your answer as there are multiple required properties where `field.required` is the right one in the example.